# Views not sorting scandinavian characters correctly

Tags: views, 8

I have created a view and applied sorting on the title field. When a title starts with the characther "å" it shows up before "a" even though its supposed to come last. The view is set to sort ASC. First i thought this was all connected to the table collation in mysql so i changed to "utf8mb4_danish_ci" and now when i do a select statement with order by directly in phpadmin i get the desired result. However when i go back to my view "ås" still comes before "at" even though its shows correctly when i do the select statement on the database directly. It seems like Drupal/views is doing something behind the scenes here, i dont know.. Anyone?

Comment: Hm, I was about to suggest that you should change the collation, but you have already done that correctly. AFAIK Views doesn't do something behind the scenes, so maybe caching is playing you a trick? Clear all caches, and report back. Merry Christmas!